# Null properties also dirty on creation?

Tags: java, hibernate, null

When I create a new instance and then [`flush()`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#flush%28%29) my Hibernate [`Session`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html), are all properties of this instance marked as dirty, including the `null` ones?

Or are only those properties dirty that aren't `null`?

Answer (score 0):

There is no dirty values not in Java neither in DBMS (Mysql for example). By default in java all primitive types takes specified zero values and all links takes null as value. The same for DBMS, when you insert a record in table field of record initialized with default values.

Comment: I'm talking about Hibernate. :-)